# pandas DataFrame to .txt with string and float values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, types

Using Python is there a way to save the values in a pandas DataFrame **of any size** to a .txt file when the DataFrame contains columns of strings as well as columns of floats?

Relevant packages:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

For example say you had the following DataFrame:

```
          NAME    0    1    2    3    4
1   0000_00_01  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2   0100_00_01  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
3  01100_11_11  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
0   1295_10_11  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

The column labelled `'NAME'` is a column of strings, whereas the other columns are floats:

```
DataFrame.values

array([['0000_00_01', 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
       ['0100_00_01', 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
       ['01100_11_11', 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
       ['1295_10_11', 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]], dtype=object)
```

If I try to save the values to a .txt file as follows:

```
np.savetxt(path+'test.txt',df.values,delimiter=' ')
```

I get the error:

`TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e')`

Is there a way to output to the .txt, while maintaining the structure of the DataFrame values (i.e. not outputting one long line of values for example)?

Comment: Did you look at the dataframe method "to_csv"?

Comment: I did not...woops! Many thanks indeed

Answer (score 1):

```
df.to_csv('test.txt', sep=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

big_list = [
        ['0000_00_01', 1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0],
        ['0100_00_01', 1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0],
        ['01100_11_11', 1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0],
        ['1295_10_11', 1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(big_list, columns = ['NAME', 0,1,2,3,4])

df.to_csv('test.txt', index = False, sep=',')
```

Use the built in pandas method "to_csv" to save the results as a text file.